# Entity Framework generic method to retrieve primary key from combobox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I have very simple issue: I have a custom control that is based on a combobox. Each instance of it has a list of database entities as Datasource (such as "Orders", "Items", "Customers" etc). I need a generic approach, that simply returns the primary key of the selected Item, regardless of its type.

I feel like this should be easy, but I have not been able to solve this. I thought it might be possible to just add a function like the following to my custom combobox-class:

```
public int GetSelectedItemsPrimaryKey()
{
    return (SelectedItem as <<DBEntitiy>>).primaryKey;
}
```

But it does not. I don't know if there is a basetype of all database entities and if so, whether it exposes it's primary key ...

**EDIT**

More detail: I have a custom control (called CheckedComboBox), that inherits from comboBox (since it will be very similar to a comboBox, just with CheckBoxes as Items). This custom control will therefore have a datasource-field. This field I want to set to a list of database-entries, for example from the table "Orders" in the database.

```
using(var db = new DBEntities())
{
    CheckedComboBox.DataSource = db.Orders.ToList();
}
```

So now I have a bunch of these custom controls, each with a different list of entries from different tables as DataSources.

Now I want to give my control the function `GetSelectedItemsPrimaryKey` which returns the primary key of the selected item. This is not a problem, if I know, which kinds of items are stored in the DataSource, I could do it like this:

```
public int GetSelectedItemsPrimaryKey()
{
    return (SelectedItem as Order).OrderPrimaryKey;
}
```

But I would have to write a function that checks if the selected item is of any type of entry from the database, which is a pain. So I want a generic method, that does the following:

```
public int GetSelectedItemsPrimaryKey()
{
    return (SelectedItem as <<DBEntitiy>>).primaryKey;
}
```

Comment: Can't understand what you exactly want to do!! Can you please be more specific. This method will be called on SelectedIndexChanged or something like that? Can you show how you do data binding for your combobox?

Comment: @Mak I tried to specify the problem a bit more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you are using entity framework as to if this is possible. Even if it is possible it is a bad idea.

If you are using proxy objects you can get to the proxy object which does contain some information like that. However, mixing in specifics of the internals of EF with your UI logic is a really bad violation of separation of concerns.

A better route is to define a base class that your entities all derive from that include those kinds of common fields. Then you can always safely cast to the base type to get the Id.

An alternative that is an option if you can't make the models inherit is to define an interface with a common of property naming. If your ID property is not able to be commonly named you can always define a notmapped computed property to return the appropriate value on each class that is named appropriately.

Comment: I actually really like your last Idea: I can simply define an interface IEntity which consists of an primaryKey-get-property that I have to implement on all tables, correct? Is that still a violation of the SOC?

Comment: No, I think it is not. You are basically letting your objects tell you how to uniquely identify them, something that while critical in a db, isn't really unique to db's and equally applies to in memory representations.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible looking at your architecture. For that kind of generic requirement you should have some base class or interface for all your entities. So you can get that property value by casting your entities to base.

For now if you can't do lot of change in your architecture, the quick and dirty solution would be to check the type of the SelectedItem using `is` operator then safely cast it to that type and get the primary key value.

```
public int GetSelectedItemsPrimaryKey(object selectedItem)
{
    if (selectedItem is Order)
    {
        return (selectedItem as Order).OrderPrimaryKey;
    }
    else if (selectedItem is Product)
    {
        return (SelectedItem as Product).ProductPrimaryKey;
    }
    //.....

}
```